# how to adjust two colors in Font Awesome?

Tags: html, css, colors, font-awesome

I would like to use Font Awesome´s Facebook icon, but I have difficulty in adjusting colors properly. My webpage background color is grey, and I would like to have an icon with mixture of white & blue, but extent of colors doesn´t adjust properly. Following is my HTML code:

```
    <a class="list-group-item"  href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Scientific-Editing-and-Proofreading/726988900763622" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa fa-facebook-square fa-5x fa-cog-fa"></i></a>
```

And following is my css:

```
.fa-cog-fa {
color: white;
background-color:blue;
}
```

And you can see the final look under following link:
[this is how my code at the end appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHZQl.jpg)

As you see, blue color is so extent such that crosses borders of white color. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: your code don't work, can you make demo yourself?

Comment: How do you want it to look in the end? Is the icon supposed to have a blue glow/border?

Comment: You can use a separate icons and put them on top of each other with css. I found a solution in: [Stackicons: Doing More with Icon Fonts](https://css-tricks.com/stackicons-icon-fonts/)

Answer (score 2):

You can stack multiple FontAwesome icons together, and with CSS, add in some extra formatting. fa-square and fa-facebook can combine well together, though you'll have to fiddle around with alignment and positioning to get it just right.

Basic markup for a stack:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Documentation: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Demo with colors, sloppily aligned: http://codepen.io/blindingstars/pen/WvVevE

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome Pro 5 now has DUOTONES, and this would always be the preferable way to use two colors in a icon.

Official Resource Link: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/duotone-icons

[image]

```
<div class="fa-3x">
  <i class="fad fa-bus-alt" style="--fa-primary-color: gold;"></i>  <!-- primary layer color defined -->
  <i class="fad fa-bus-alt" style="--fa-primary-color: orangered;"></i> <!-- primary layer color defined -->
  <i class="fad fa-fill-drip" style="--fa-secondary-color: limegreen;"></i>  <!-- secondary layer color defined -->
  <i class="fad fa-fill-drip" style="--fa-secondary-color: rebeccapurple;"></i> <!-- secondary layer color defined -->
  <i class="fad fa-battery-full" style="--fa-primary-color: limegreen; --fa-secondary-color: dimgray;"></i> <!-- secondary + primary layer color defined -->
  <i class="fad fa-battery-quarter" style="--fa-primary-color: orange; --fa-secondary-color: dimgray;"></i> <!-- secondary + primary layer color defined -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's how the font is set. You can use the other facebook font `<i class="fa fa-facebook'></i>` that FontAwesome has and then manipulate it with CSS to look something similar. Here's a fiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/q1pL3bop/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't, easily. Fontawesome (or any font for that matter) has only two "colors": the foreground color and transparent. Using fonts with multiple colors requires some kind of overlay technique (I.e. Putting two icons on top of each other), which may be tricky to get right.

If you want color, stick with SVG, or even PNG.

Comment: Could you please link some good tutorials&articles, explaining how can I do this with SVG?

Comment: It is not harder to use SVG than any other image. Use it as you would a PNG, e.g using the background-image CSS attribute. Here's a two color SVG Facebook icon for example https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/F_icon.svg

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Font Awesome's SVG to get the effect that you're looking for. With using a "font" the pseudo element ::before extends past the element itself. When using an SVG it fits the element perfectly.

You can find out more information on this at: https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/